# IzPack Shortcut Nightmare

Tags: java, izpack, shortcut-file

I'm at my wit's end with this.

I have a VERY simple installation descriptor for izpack for a two-package Java app on Windows. Everything works as intended EXCEPT for the shortcut creation. The shortcut panel doesn't seem right, for a start. The label "ShortcutPanel.regular.startup" is displayed instead of "run at startup" or anything of the sort in the startup execution checkbox.

[image: Something's not quite right...]

After running the installer, the shortcuts simply aren't created. Here's what my install.xml looks like, it's pretty straightforward:

```
<izpack:installation version="5.0"
xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">

<info>
    <appname>application_name</appname>
    <appversion>2.0.0</appversion>
    <appsubpath>myapp</appsubpath>
    <javaversion>1.8</javaversion>
</info>

<locale>
    <langpack iso3="bra" />
</locale>

<resources>
    <res src="shortcutSpec.xml" id="shortcutSpec.xml"/>
</resources>

<variables>
    <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.windows" value="C:/Sistemas"/>
</variables>

<guiprefs width="800" height="600" resizable="no">
    <laf name="substance">
        <os family="windows" />
        <os family="unix" />
        <param name="variant" value="mist-silver" />
    </laf>
    <modifier key="useHeadingPanel" value="yes" />
</guiprefs>

<panels>
    <panel classname="HelloPanel" />
    <panel classname="DefaultTargetPanel" />
    <panel classname="ShortcutPanel" />
    <panel classname="InstallPanel" />
    <panel classname="FinishPanel" />
</panels>

<natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </native>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </native>
</natives>

<packs>
    <pack name="Pack1" required="yes">
        <description>one of the packs it's a jar</description>
        <file src="lib/pack1.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/pack1subdir"
            override="true">
        </file>
        <file src="imagens/logo.ico" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/pack1subdir/imagens/"
            override="true" />
        <executable targetfile="lib/pack1.jar" type="jar"
            stage="never"></executable>
    </pack>
    <pack name="Pack2" required="yes">
        <description>the other pack</description>
        <file src="lib/pack2.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/pack2subdir"
            override="true">
        </file>
        <file src="imagens/update.ico" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/pack2subdir/imagens/"
            override="true" />
        <executable targetfile="lib/pack2.jar" type="jar"
            stage="never"></executable>
    </pack>
</packs>
```

Then there's the shortcutSpec.xml. My pom moves it to my staging directory:

```
<izpack:shortcuts version="5.0"
xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/shortcuts" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/shortcuts http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-shortcuts-5.0.xsd">

<lateShortcutInstall />

<shortcut name="pack1" programGroup="false"
    desktop="true" applications="false" startMenu="no" startup="true"
    target="java -jar $INSTALL_PATH/pack1subdir/pack1.jar"
    workingDirectory="$INSTALL_PATH/pack1subdir/">
    <createForPack name="pack1" />
</shortcut>

<shortcut name="pack2" programGroup="false"
    desktop="true" applications="false" startMenu="no" startup="true"
    target="java -jar $INSTALL_PATH/pack2subdir/pack1.jar"
    workingDirectory="$INSTALL_PATH/pack2subdir/">
    <createForPack name="pack2" />
</shortcut>
```

The installer simply doesn't create any shortcuts anywhere. It finishes with no error messages no logs no stack traces no nothing.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that by going into the *izPack/lib/izpack-core-5.0.9.jar* and opening the */com/izforge/izpack/bin/langpacks/installer/* folder in it. Then editing the bra.xml file and adding the following line:

```
<str id="ShortcutPanel.regular.startup" txt="Iniciar com o Windows"/>
```

Then save and update the file in the jar and rebuild your instalation.